# Existence of $x$ such that $2^x =a,3^x=b,5^x=c$ for some integers $a,b,c$

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation, transcendence-theory

Conjecture:

> There does not exist a non-integer $x$ such that
>
> $$2^x=a$$ $$3^x=b$$ $$5^x=c$$
>
> where $a,b,c$ are all integers.

---

I'm aware that the similar question

> There does not exist a non-integer $y$ such that
>
> $$2^y=A$$ $$3^y=B$$
>
> where $A,B$ are all integers.

is a famous unsolved problem.

*(evidence in the corrolaries [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_exponentials_conjecture) or [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17560/if-2x-and-3x-are-integers-must-x-be-as-well))*

My idea was that the addition of the condition $5^x$ made the problem easier and therefore solvable.

Comment: Why do you think this additional criterion makes it easier? Do you have anything concrete to add?

Comment: Its like a system of linear equations I guess. The more equations you have , the easier to solve , or show there is no solution.

Comment: AFAIK, the $2$, $3$, and $5$ version isn't an unsolved problem. There was a question on MSE about a week ago asking "if $n^x$ is an integer for all positive integers $n$, then $x$ is an integer". One of the comments suggested a link providing a proof that $2$, $3$, and $5$ are sufficient, hence providing a proof of this problem. I'll try to find that question later.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17560/if-2x-and-3x-are-integers-must-x-be-as-well

Comment: @EdwardJiang that would be very nice. Thanks in advance !

Comment: @gtrrebel Thanks I added the link.

Comment: [This question is possibly related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1034875/131263).

Comment: Added pages from Lang book in answer.

Answer (score 8):

Theorem of Siegel that for real $\lambda$ and distinct primes $p,q,r,$ the numbers $$  p^\lambda, \;   q^\lambda, \;   r^\lambda,   $$
cannot all be rational unless $\lambda$ is an integer.

See page 455 in Alaoglu and Erdos, *[On Highly Composite and Similar Numbers](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1944-03.pdf)* (1944), also chapter 2 of *Introduction to Transcendental Numbers* by S. Lang.

I see there is also a book *Transcendental Numbers* by our hero, C.L. Siegel, that could easily give the first polished discussion of the result, which is just what we call a "personal communication" in the Alaoglu Erdos article.

I do not have the Lang book from the library yet. Apparently this covers the same material, and is certainly from the same time: [LANG PDF](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/SB/SB_1964-1966__9_/SB_1964-1966__9__407_0/SB_1964-1966__9__407_0.pdf)

From the book, now clear how it relates, see Corollary 1, with the definition of multiplicatively independent middle of page 8 :

[image]

[image]

This (Theorem 1, I guess) is this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_exponentials_theorem

Comment: IS there no short answer ??

Comment: @mick, I do not see why there would be. I requested a copy of Lang from the library, not here yet. Most problems in number theory that are not constructed as exercises for books are extremely difficult, or currently impossible. It takes knowledge to make an approachable question.

Comment: It's the Six Exponentials Theorem, and no short proof is known, nor is any expected.

Comment: Compare https://www.sixflags.com/america

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Days_Seven_Nights

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation