# How to prove that $2^x,3^x,5^x\in\mathbb N$ implies $x\in\mathbb N$?

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation

Let $x\in\mathbb R$ and suppose that $2^x,3^x$ and $5^x$ are all integers. Does it imply that $x$ is also necessarily an integer?

I read somewhere that the answer is "Yes" and a proof is known, but I haven't seen a proof and was not able to prove it myself. Could you please help me to find a proof?

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087841/existence-of-x-such-that-2x-a-3x-b-5x-c-for-some-integers-a-b-c/1087922#1087922

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17560/if-2x-and-3x-are-integers-must-x-be-as-well)

It follows from the [Six Exponentials Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_exponentials_theorem). Apparently.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087841/existence-of-x-such-that-2x-a-3x-b-5x-c-for-some-integers-a-b-c/1087922#1087922