# If $m^x$ an integer for all naturals $m$ then $x$ and integer

Tags: number-theory

I have seen this result somewhere: If $x$ is a positive real number such that $m^x$ is an integer for all natural numbers $m$, then $x$ is an integer.

It is quite interesting and I have some thoughts on it, but I have not yet solved it. By the way, is this famous?

Comment: This was asked a few weeks ago.  You should be able to find it with a search.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087841/existence-of-x-such-that-2x-a-3x-b-5x-c-for-some-integers-a-b-c/1087922#1087922