# How can I make this kind of proof rigorous?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, proof-writing, diophantine-equations

I have transformed a Diophantine equation into the form
$$
\frac{a-b-3}{a-b-1} = \frac{2(b-1)(a+1)}{a^2+b^2},  \tag{$\star$}
$$
where $a > b \ge 1$ are integers. I want to prove that $a-b=3$ [thus forcing $b=1$]. It’s easy to show that $1 ≤ a-b ≤ 3$ has only the one desired solution. Now assuming $a-b ≥ 4$, I can say
\begin{align}
  \frac{a-b-3}{a-b-1} \simeq 1,
\end{align}
and thus
\begin{align}
  1 &\simeq \frac{2(b-1)(a+1)}{a^2+b^2}  \\
  a^2+b^2 &\simeq 2(b-1)(a+1) \\
       &= 2ab+2(b-a-1)  \\
  \therefore\quad (a-b)^2 &\simeq 2(b-a-1) ≤ 2(-4-1)=-10.
\end{align}

With a strict equality, this would clearly be impossible; QED. The proof might also be valid *if* I can qualify *precisely* what is meant by “$\simeq$”, such that the contradiction holds.

> **QUESTION**: How can I make this method of proof rigorous?

**EDIT:** In case it helps, I have proven that
$$ab = 4(256n^3-640n^2+533n-148) \qquad\text{and}\qquad a-b=16n-13$$
for some $n \ge 1$, and need to prove that $n=1$ is the only solution. Combining those two equations yields
$$a^2+b^2=(8n-7)(256n^2-384n+145),$$
which has certain implications I might be able to leverage…

Comment: Why would the LHS be approx 1? If a-b=3, wouldn’t the numerator be zero?

Comment: @BenjaminWang: Yes, that’s the point of my proof: If a-b>3, then the LHS is approximately 1.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach likely can't be easily fixed. Because of the coefficient of 2, you need the fraction to be $ \geq 1$. However, you can only bound it by $ 1 - \epsilon$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Claim:** For $C > 2$, and arbitrary constants $D, E, F$, then the inequality

$$ a^2 + b^ 2 - Cab - Da - Eb - F \leq 0. $$

always has integer solutions.

**Proof:** We want to find

$$ (a-b)^2 \leq (C - 2 ) ab + Da + Eb + F. $$

Since $ C - 2 > 0$, we can take $ b = a+1, a  \rightarrow \infty$.
Then, the RHS is dominated by $a^2$ hence tends to $ + \infty$, so is $ \geq 1$ for some large enough $a$. So, (integer) solutions exist.

**Corollary:** With the restriction of $ a - b \geq N$, since $\frac{a-b-3}{a-b-1 } \geq \frac{N-3}{N-1}$, in OP's solution, we have

$$a^2 + b^2 - \frac{2(N-1)}{N-3} (b-1)(a+1) \leq 0.$$

This has integer roots, hence we cannot just use this approach to reach a contradiction.

Since this proof approach doesn't work, we cannot make it rigorous (in it's current form).

For the more general case, to show that $ (a-b)^2 < 0$

- If $ C = 2$, then it greatly depends on the constants (and should be pretty obvious.).
- If $ |C| < 2 $, then the RHS is eventually negative, so we can restrict to considering "small" cases.

---

To solve the problem, cross multiply and factor to get

$$ (a-b)^3 - (a+b)^2 - 2 = 0. $$

The problem is then equivalent to showing that $ x^3 - y^2 = 2 $ only has one solution, namely $ (3, 5)$.

[See solution here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149107/prove-that-x-3-y-2-2-only-has-one-solution-3-5), which uses ideas of $\mathbb{Z} [ \sqrt{-2} ] $.
It suggests that you need much more advanced tools than what you just listed out.

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there anything I can try to do with ($\star$) in order to be able to rescue the basic approach? _e.g.,_ if the LHS was $(a-b+1)/(a-b-1)$ [which is greater than $1$], would there be a possible attack?

Comment: Obviously, that was the “Diophantine equation” I started with.  ;) I’m trying to find a more elementary solution than the existing ones.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan See my edit. I believe that line of attack will not lead to a solution. This requires some "high power" stuff.

Comment: There are lots of examples of equations that people once thought required “high power stuff” that ultimately didn’t. Indeed, recently a non-high-power elementary solution for the equation $X^3-Y^2=2$ was found!

Comment: I don't think it's that likely in this case, esp because the competition math community has been bashing against it. It's a common enough (and innocuous looking) problem that many (myself included years ago) have given it a try. But, like you said, don't like that discourage you.

Comment: Question: You say “to show that $(a-b)^2 < 0\dots$” How is that possible? It’s the square of an integer!?

Comment: @KierenMacMillan That's one way to show that there's a contradiction, hence there are no solutions. Wasn't that what you were going for?